# Checking two arrays for similar elements, returns correct values for some tests, incorrect for others

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function which intends to see if two arrays contain similar elements.

This is the main function:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 2};
int arrb[] = {1, 2, 1};
int a = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
int b = (sizeof(arrb)/sizeof(arrb[0]));
cout << checkForSimilar(arr,arrb,a,b);
```

and the following function:

```
int checkForSimilar(int arraya[], int arrayb[], int a, int b)
{
    if (a != b) return 0; else
    {
        int foundSwitch = 0;
        int found = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
                if (arraya[i] == arrayb[j])
                {
                    foundSwitch = 1;
                    break;
                } else foundSwitch = 0;
            }
        }
        return foundSwitch;
    }
}
```

The function is not returning expected values, however. In the above example, for example, it should return 0, but it returns 1. This function returns the correct value for some arrays and not the correct one for others. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

**EDIT:** I worded the above function poorly. It's an equality test, where both arrays need to contain the same elements. However, they don't have to be in the same order.

Comment: I step in your code and it's output is '1', base your function these two arrays have similar items.

Comment: Do you mean equality by your function?

Comment: Yes, the function is to check if both arrays have same elements, regardless of order.

Comment: @DemCodeLines Maybe compare two sorted arrays?

Comment: How do you define "similar" for your program?

Comment: @RSahu what do you mean by how I "define"? As in what I intend? The two arrays should have the same elements, regardless of order. {1,1,0} and {1,0,1} should return true, because they both have two 1's and one 0.

Comment: @DemCodeLines You could accomplish this by storing each array in a `std::map<int, int>` where the key is the integer, and the data is the count .  Then compare the maps using `==`.  Example:  http://ideone.com/6DfIDI  Example 2: http://ideone.com/zDeX8r

Comment: What about {0,1,2} and {0,1,9}? Are they "similar"?

Comment: @NickyC No, because the other array does not have 9 in it. I worded it poorly, the two arrays need to have the same values, but they don't have to be in the same order. It's basically an equality test.

Comment: @DemCodeLines Read my comment.  Is that satisfactory?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I appreciate your effort, but in this particular case, I need it with just the simply way (so nested for loops).

Comment: @DemCodeLines - So you need to test to see if the count of each integer in each array is the same?  f you're going to do that, where in your original code do you store the count of each number?

Comment: You are just checking the existence of elements of one array in another one.
Its would fail e.g. for [1,1,2,2] and [1,2,1,1]
The simplest way would be to sort the two arrays first and then compare their elements one by one.

Comment: @DemCodeLines You didn't answer my comment -- are you not only supposed to know what items are similar, but also the count of each item to make sure they match?

Comment: @DemCodeLines you can use stl algorithms to perform this in a neat way without affecting the original arrays, as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and more efficient is to sort before comparing (`n log n` vs `n²`):

```
bool checkForSimilar(int arraya[], int arrayb[], int a, int b)
{
    std::sort(arraya, arraya + a);
    std::sort(arrayb, arrayb + b);
    return a == b && std::equal(arraya, arraya + a, arrayb);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/xY7IMf)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the effectiveness of std::sort before me, didn't see you post before I had posted mine

Answer (score 0):

The function you wrote says the two arrays are similar because you're simply checking if each of the elements in the first array exist in the second array. In the test example you've put here, it is the case so you're getting 1 as a return.

Since you want each element in an array to match with exactly one element of the other you should do it like this:

```
    int foundSwitch = 0;
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < b; j++)
        {
            if (arraya[i] == arrayb[j])
            {
                foundSwitch = 1;
                int temp = arrayb[i];
                arrayb[i]=arrayb[j];
                arrayb[j]=temp;
                break;
            } else foundSwitch = 0;
        }
    }
    free[] foundvalues;
    return foundSwitch;
```

Comment: That's not supposed to happen. It should check if each element exists "as-is" in the other array. If there are two 2's, then there should be two 2's in the other array too.

Comment: Ok I understand. I'll edit my code to have something that works for that.

Comment: Although this makes it very easy to complete, I need it to work with nested for loops and the simple way, for this specific case. But I do appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: @DemCodeLines The answer *does* use a nested loop.

Comment: I don't have the ability to use vectors in this case.

Comment: What if we were checking the two arrays for the same elements at the same location, but were asked to use nested for loops and no pointers/vectors/{anything other than arrays}?

Comment: Well in this case either you sort the arrays then do a simple test to see if the two arrays match. In this case I assume you can't so if you can't make an array for matching every element in arrayb you would have to rewrite arrayb. I'm changing my answer to do that.

Comment: `bool* foundvalues = new bool[b*sizeof(bool)];`  This is not right.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie   Sorry for the minor slip in writing, I changed it since that method was also not allowed anyway

Comment: Anyway now you're swapping the values in the second array so every time you find a match in the second array you won't compare it with the left array again. You also have to do less loops (only half as many) so it's more efficient.

Comment: @meneldal However the arrays are being mutated.  I don't know if this is the desired effect.

Comment: Well there's another answer which sorts them. I don't even know if it is possible without allocating another array or mutating the second one.

Comment: @meneldal Correct, it requires more storage.

Answer (score 0):

First off the code breaks when it finds one similarity. If you want to check if both arrays have the same elements (and in the same position), you might want to change it like this:

```
if (a != b) 
    return 0; 
else
{
    int foundSwitch = 0;
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        if (arraya[i] != arrayb[i])
        {
            foundSwitch = 0;
            break;
        }
        else foundSwitch = 1;
    }
    return foundSwitch;
}
```

This code will only work if both the elements and their order are the same (ex. {3, 2, 1} and {1, 2, 3} will return 0).

You can use a for loop if you don't care about order.

```
if (a != b) 
    return 0; 
else
{
    int foundSwitch;
    int numToCheck;

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        numToCheck = arraya[i];
        foundSwitch = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            if (numToCheck == arrayb[j])
            {
                foundSwitch = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (foundSwitch == 0)
            break;
    }
    return foundSwitch;
}
```

Basically this checks the i element in arrayA. If that element is in arrayB then in breaks the inner j loop and sets found switch to 1. By default its gonna be 0 so if it goes unchanged by the time the j loop ends then you found an element that is in array a that is not in b.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the correct way. Is it technically impossible to do what I need to do without using anything other than simple nested for loops?

Comment: I just edited the answer to show a way to check if the array is the same if you don't care about the order of the elements.

Comment: This actually doesn't answer to the question, it just checks if the two arrays are identical, not if they have the same elements in a potential different order.

Answer (score 0):

your code must be:
`int checkForSimilar(int arraya[], int arrayb[], int a, int b)

```
{
    if (a != b) return 0; else
    {
        int foundSwitch = 1;
        int found = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
                if (arraya[i] == arrayb[j])
                {
                    foundSwitch = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(foundSwitch == 0){
                break;
            }
        }
        return foundSwitch;
    }
}`
```

Comment: This function returns 0 for {2,1} vs {2,1}, which should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above, you are just checking the existence of elements of one array in another one. Its would fail e.g. for [1,1,2,2] and [1,2,1,1] The simplest way would be to sort the two arrays first and then compare their elements one by one

```
int compare_int( const void* a, const void* b )
{
    if( *(int*)a == *(int*)b ) return 0;
    return *(int*)a < *(int*)b ? -1 : 1;
}


int checkForSimilar(int arraya[], int arrayb[], int a, int b)
{
  if (a != b) {
   return 0;
  }
  qsort(arraya, a, sizeof(int), compare_int); // O(n logn)
  qsort(arrayb, b, sizeof(int), compare_int); // O(n logn)

  for (int index = 0; index < a; ++index) {  // O(n)
    if (arraya[index] != arrayb[index]) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Even complexity-wise its O(nlogn), so better than nested for loops which would be O(n2).

EDIT : Using std::sort as suggested by [PaulMcKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133316/paulmckenzie)

```
int checkForSimilar(int arraya[], int arrayb[], int a, int b)
{
  if (a != b) {
   return 0;
  }
  std::sort(std::begin(arraya), std::end(arraya));
  std::sort(std::begin(arrayb), std::end(arrayb));

  for (int index = 0; index < a; ++index) {
    if (arraya[index] != arrayb[index]) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use that as an answer, at the very least use `std::sort`.  The `std::sort` works for arrays just fine without all of the pointer madness.  Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ace93e1569cd0d09

Answer (score 0):

A probably more efficient way is to use **STL algorithms**.
As an example below which copies the arrays to **prevent that the originals get edited**, then using **`std::sort`** to sort before checking for **`std::equal`**

```
bool isSimilar(int arr[], const int& size1, int arr2[], const int& size2)
{
    int temp1[size1];
    int temp2[size2];

    copy(arr, arr + size1, temp1);   // copy values into temps to avoid
    copy(arr2, arr2 + size2, temp2); // editing to the originals

    sort(temp1, temp1 + size1);      // Sort for performance
    sort(temp2, temp2 + size2);

    if (equal(temp1, temp1 + size1, temp2))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]  {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int arr2[] {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};

    const int size1 = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
    const int size2 = (sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(*arr2));

    cout << (isSimilar(arr, size1, arr2, size2) ? "Similar" : "Not similar");
}
```

When the function returns, **the original elements remain unmodified.**

This code is not only is **faster** but it improves **readability** and looks more elegant.